# Unsure why my method isnt following what i wanted it to do

Tags: java, arrays

Trying to make a lottery game which compares users input to a randomly generated Array which stores the lottery answers ( not working 100% unsure as to why sometimes it does not pickup on answers and sometimes will pick up extra answers. EG. Total Counter is broken?). However my method for validation is incorrect and i am unsure how to fix this any ideas?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestingClassDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int input; //Holds keyboard input
        final int TOTAL_ANSWERS = 10; //Number of answers
        int[] guesses = new int[TOTAL_ANSWERS]; //Array to hold answers

        //Creates a Scanner object for keyboard input
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Gets the users Input
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Lottery!");

        for(int i = 0; i < guesses.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter digit " + (i+1) + ": ");
            input = userInput.nextInt();

            while(!validate(guesses[i]))
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a digit between 1-9");
                System.out.print("Enter digit " + (i+1) + ": ");
                input = userInput.nextInt();
            }
        }

        //Creates a Lottery Object
        TestingClass myLottery = new TestingClass(guesses);


        System.out.print("\nCorrect Numbers: " + (myLottery.totalCorrect()));

    }//End of Main Method
    public static boolean validate(int a)
    {
        boolean status;

        if( a == 1 || a == 2 || a == 3 || a == 4 || a == 5 || a == 6 || a == 7 || a == 8 || a == 9)
            status = true;
        else 
            status = false;
        return status;

    }
}//End of TestingClassDemo
```

Other Class

```
public class TestingClass {

    private int[] lotteryNumbers = new int[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < lotteryNumbers.length; i++)
    {
        lotteryNumbers[i] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
        System.out.print(lotteryNumbers[i]+ " ");
    }
    }//End of LOOP

    //Creates a Private Array for lotteryNumbers the user Guesses
    private int[] lotteryGuesses = new int[10];

    //Creates a Private int totalCorrect whether correct guesses are stored
    private int totalCorrect = 0;

    //Appends lotteryGuesses to lotteryNumbers for comparison
    public TestingClass(int[] lotteryNumbers)
    {
        lotteryGuesses = lotteryNumbers;
    }

    /** Compares whether the uses LotteryGuess are correct
     and if they are increases total Correct
     */
    public int totalCorrect()
    {
        for( int x = 0; x < lotteryNumbers.length; x++)
        {
            if (lotteryGuesses[x] == lotteryNumbers[x])
            {
                totalCorrect += 1;
            }
        }
        return totalCorrect;
    }
}//End of Public Class TestingClass
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Hard to answer the question without knowing what you expected the program to do, and what it actually did instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input = userInput.nextInt();

while(!validate(guesses[i]))
{
}
```

You're missing something here. You should validate your input, and copy it into the guesses array once it's valid.

```
input = userInput.nextInt();

while(!validate(input))
{ 
    ...  
}
guesses[i] = input;
```

Comment: Still throwing the same error. If i add a break statement in, it works however it breaks the loop and increments i. And if i add guesses[i] = input;  to the end when it doesnt meet validate criteria it starts an infinite loop.

Comment: Works for me: https://ideone.com/M3alpR

Comment: Yeah for some reason it wasn't working but your's worked :)